# how to make a regex input convention optionally?

Tags: python

i try to use a valid hour - minute clock form. im using:

```
if data :=  re.search(r'(.[+0-9])(:.[0-9])? (AM|PM) to (.[+0-9])(:.[0-9])? (AM|PM)', x):
    print(len(data.groups()))
else:
    print('False')
```

i think my code has an optional part(i mean minutes), so '12:54 AM to 23:34 PM' is acceptable, but when i enter: '2 AM to 5 PM', the code fails and the else line executes.

Comment: it is because your first parenthsis is expecting at least two characters

Comment: Why do you have `+` in the character sets?

Comment: Why do you have `PM` along with `23:34`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your optional part if working fine. What fails is that you force to have 2 characters and `2` is not recognized (`12` works).

Also, it's unclear why you include `+` in the characters to match, maybe a misunderstanding of how repetition works?

You can use:

```
re.search(r'([0-9]{1,2})(:[0-9]{1,2})? (AM|PM) to ([0-9]{1,2})(:[0-9]{1,2})? (AM|PM)', x)
```